# Segmentation fault only for one file?

Tags: c, file, io, segmentation-fault

So I am trying to read the input from one file(ride.in), do a calculation with it, and print the result out in another file(ride.out). When I try with the first file using fscanf, it works fine. It also works when I am just printing using printf. However, it fails to work when I try to write to the file using fprintf, resulting in Segmentation Fault: 11. How is this even possible?

Code that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main () {
FILE *fin  = fopen ("ride.in", "r");
FILE *fout = fopen ("ride.out", "w");

char UFO[6], group[6];

fscanf(fin, "%s", UFO);
int sumUFO = 0, sumGroup = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    sumUFO += (int) UFO[i];
}

fscanf(fin, "%s", group);

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    sumGroup += (int) group[i];
}

fclose(fin);

if(sumUFO == sumGroup)
    printf("GO");
else
    printf("STAY");

exit (0);
}
```

However, when I change the last if statement to use fprintf instead of printf, I get a Segmentation Fault: 11. This is the last if statement. Nothing else has been changed:

```
if(sumUFO == sumGroup)
    fprintf(fout,"GO");
else
    fprintf(fout,"STAY");
```

Input ride.in currently looks like:

```
AAAAAA
AAAAAA
```

Output ride.out is currently an empty text file.

Comment: Check for the return value of `fopen` i.e. if `fout` is not `NULL`.

Comment: do your files have more than 6 bytes?

Comment: You're probably exceeding the bounds of UFO and/or group and corrupting the fout pointer. What exactly does your input file look like?

Comment: You are missing all error checking. Functions like `fopen()` or `fscanf()` can fail. Using `%s` with a bounded string on unknown input can also cause buffer overflows, you should tell `fscanf()` what the size of your buffer actually is.

Comment: in function: `fscanf()`  1) check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  (In this case, the returned value must be `1` )   2) the format string `%s` has not max characters limit, so the input is easily overrun resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  ---AND--- does not consume any `white space` between the two input strings. Suggest: `if( 1 != fscanf(fin, " %*s", sizeof(group)-1, group);`  and similarly for the other call to fscanf()

Comment: @thumbmunkeys I have uploaded the input and output as well.

Comment: @keithmo I have uploaded the input and output as well

Comment: regarding this line: `sumUFO += (int) UFO[i];` and this line: ` sumGroup += (int) group[i];`  Are you sure you want to ascii value of the characters?

Comment: @user3629249 Yes, that was the calculation part. That part I am sure works, I am just stuck on the input and output throwing segmentation faults

Comment: @user3629249 I have tried to check the value of fscanf, but when I do fscanf(fout, "%s", temp); it just returns the segmentation fault, blocking all output from the program no matter where the output is placed.

Comment: There's your problem -- you're reading a 6 character string into a 6 character array. Make your arrays one larger so there's room for the terminating null. Also, `"%6s"` would be a much safer format specifier for fscanf.

Comment: The function: `fscanf()` automatically appends a NUL byte to the end of a string read by '%s`, so a total of 7 characters will be written into each of the input buffers `UFO[]` and 'group[]`, however those arrays are only 6 characters long, The result is writing past the end of the arrays.  This is undefined behaviour and (as you have noted) leads to a seg fault event.

Comment: @keithmo oh wow thank you I can't believe it was such a dumb mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you so much! That fixed it.

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){`  for this scenario, this code will work, however, it would be better to write: `for(int i = 0; grade[i]; i++){`  so the loop exits when the NUL byte (placed there by the call to `fscanf()` is encountered.

Comment: @keithmo,  could you post an answer, so the OP can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading a 6 character string into a 6 character array. Make your arrays one larger so there's room for the terminating null. Also, "%6s" would be a much safer format specifier for fscanf (otherwise you risk a buffer overflow if the input file is malformed).

Answer (score 1):

1. after calling 1st fscanf() it is reading 6 char bt when u r calling 2nd fscanf() it is not finding the pointer from where next char have to read.
   for that u have to use lseek().

here is the code =>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main () {
FILE *fin  = fopen ("ride.in", "r");
FILE *fout = fopen ("ride.out", "w");
int i;
char UFO[6], group[6];

fscanf(fin, "%s", UFO);
int sumUFO = 0, sumGroup = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
 sumUFO += (int) UFO[i];
 printf("%c => %d \n",UFO[i],sumUFO );
}
fseek(fin,6,SEEK_SET);

fscanf(fin, "%s", group);
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
 sumGroup += (int) group[i];
 printf("%c =>> %d \n",group[i],sumGroup );

}

fclose(fin);

if(sumUFO == sumGroup)
 fprintf(fout,"GO");
else
 fprintf(fout,"STAY");

return 0;
}
```

in this code fprintf() is working fine ....